# HTTP Send port timing out in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I have a static one-way port configured for HTTP which sends XML documents to an external website. It's been working fine for over a year but lately it has been throwing errors

> The HTTP send adapter cannot complete the transmission within the specified time. Destination: https://xyz.example.com

I've tried extending the timeout on the send port and the errors keep happening. The vendor says there have been no changes on their end, I have made no changes to the server and the network team says no changes have been made either.

I've tested the interface with PostMan and it works every time I try it.
Resuming the messages does nothing as I get the same error. What I've noticed is that if I reset the host instance then the messages start flowing.

Any clues?

Comment: Does the port have ordered delivery configured?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a lot of HTTP request and the Outbound Throttling is activated? Check the performance counter Message delivery throttling state associated with BizTalk:MessageAgent performance object category to measure the current throttling state and see if it is different from 0.

[Host Throttling Performance Counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578302.aspx)

[How BizTalk Server Implements Host Throttling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559893.aspx)

Comment: I had a couple of traces for a 3 hour period grabbing all kinds of counters. The state never went to anything other than 0. I am going to focus on the throttling state and grab a trace for the whole day and see if that shows anything. Thanks

Comment: Grab "Message delivery throttling state" of the Host that is associated with your static one-way Send Port configured for HTTP which sends XML documents to an external website.

Comment: I don't know if this image helps much but I took the trace with the throttling state and also the HTTP send adapter for the whole day. At around 4:40 PM the messages started timing out. The only sure thing that fixes it is if I bounce the host instance which you can see in the image. [Does this image tell you anything](http://i.imgur.com/GpEvVaq.png)

Comment: Can you add to your performance counters "Message Publishing Throttling State"? Seems that there is not problem on sending.

Comment: I added the Message Publishing Throttling State and doesn't seem to change from 0 You can [see](https://i.imgur.com/utBwXTZ.png) right around 10:30 CST I bounced the Service and resumed all the queued messages and then the server went back to normal. At this point I don't see what else it could be and may have to reach out to my network team unless you could think of anything else it could be.

Comment: Seems that there isn't a problem with BizTalk Throttling, maybe it's a problem with the number of request or connections open to your destination server. You can see [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547969.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for HTTP Adapter Configuration and Tuning Parameters, maybe it helps you.

Comment: I have just remembered the problem of TCP/IP Port Exhaustion (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd802205.aspx), maybe this helps you too.

Comment: @felixmodelo, thanks for the reply. I looked into what you suggested and I am still trying to understand the text I am getting from netstat. If I find anything I'll reply.

Comment: I was able to capture some more data and it does show that throttling is kicking in. Maybe one of you can make heads or tails of these traces. [trace 1](https://i.imgur.com/00rGusA.png), [trace 2](https://i.imgur.com/kuYxTYY.png), [trace 3](https://i.imgur.com/m04EmJS.png). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which is the value of the Message Delivery Throttling State? This value identifies the problem (1: Throttling due to imbalanced message delivery rate, 3: Throttling due to high in-process message count, ...)

Comment: The green trace shows the message delivery throttling state

Answer (score 1):

On trace 3, the value is 1, then "Throttling due to imbalanced message delivery rate". This means that "Message delivery incoming rate for the host instance exceeds the Message delivery outgoing rate * the specified Rate overdrive factor (percent)". The send port can't send messages as fast it receives new ones.

You can check both rates with performance counters:

[image]

You can increment the "Rate overdrive factor (percent)" at the Host properties to allow more load, by default is 125 (input rate can be as much 25% above output rate, then it begin to Throttling):

[image]

Or adjust the Sampling Window Duration or Minimum Number of Samples. It depends of the behaviour of your load.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. The only thing that makes me thing that may not be the case is that the error I am getting is an HTTP timeout which would suggest to me that the recipient is overloaded with messages? I will add the new traces you suggested and see what I can see. Thanks!

Comment: News about this problem? How about the Message Delivery performance counters?

Comment: Thanks for following up. I have captured the traces and I can see that the incoming rate is higher than the delivery rate then suddenly the throttling will kick in with code 1. Now I am trying to figure out why that incoming rate is higher than the outgoing rate. I've been capturing the CPU and memory as well to see if there's a correlation. However, the fact that the error still is HTTP timeout makes me think that it's something with the network. Once I rule out that the CPU and memory are OK when the problem happens then I think i can say that it's a network problem.

Comment: The error happened 2 more times and the CPU and Memory were normal while the throttling was happening. I think it's safe to say that something is wrong on the network that keeps the send port from making a connection. Any clues on how I can determine this without involving my network team? Something I can do locally on the server?